# Forcing Nautilus to use Kerberos (Active Directory) authentication

Tags: nautilus, active-directory

Is there a way to get Nautilus or any other file manager that runs on Ubuntu 11.04 to use Kerberos for authentication?

I'm using Likewise Open to join machines to the domain, and I can't type in passwords for every user on every computer that needs to mount a network share. I've been able to get Kerberos [working with the command line `smbclient`](http://www.likewise.com/community/index.php/forums/viewthread/1102/), but oddly Kerberos does not seem to be Nautilus-integrated. I also checked the SSH config file, and it looks like you can enable GSSAPIAuthentication, but it only works for Kerberos v2, not the current version, which I think is v5.

Comment: I'm interested in this as well either with LikeWise-Open or Centrify.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with Microsoft's Active Directory or Kerberos, but hopefully this will help you out.

Nautilus uses gvfs as it's backend for mounting everything. Anything mounted with gvfs shows up in the navigation pane on the left. I'm not sure if it supports Kerberos authentication, but it does support mount smb shares.

```
sudo apt-get install gvfs-bin
gvfs-mount smb://<server name>/$USER
```

Comment: This is a useless reply. I am looking for Nautilus integration, not mounting something manually.

Comment: My point was that if nautilus's backend, gvfs, could mount the share, then Nautilus should be able to as well.